# HTML5 Javascript - Using Lat/Lon on a map without actually drawing a map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, latitude-longitude, easeljs

I need to use Longitude and Latitude coordinates on a map that will be loaded in by an external program, and I need to be able to draw things on this map and be able to zoom in and out. Thing is, I cannot draw this map, and I need to be able to interact with both the map elements and with what I'm drawing.

I tried using Google, and found that I was able to control either my canvas or the map, but not both at the same time. Plus, I could not draw things properly on top of Google's map (I'm using Easel.js).

If anyone has any sources or advice, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should provide more infomrations, the external program is an HTML5 app or something else ? what you have to draw ? what is the job of the javascript code ?

Comment: What it's going to be is an ATC demo displaying flights over an area (the demo is to see if HTML5 is a suitable front-end). The stuff I'm drawing in Easel will include small, clickable objects that will move across the screen (the flights) as well as an interface including buttons and menus, pop-ups and so-forth. The flights just need to be projected onto the map below.

[Here is an example image.](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/eRAM.jpg)

Comment: Straight lines? or curved?

Comment: If a client wants curved lines, they'll get curved lines lol.

Comment: Are you good at geometry? Because the only way I see you putting a curved line is with lat,lng cords which will be very difficult. I am pretty sure that there is nothing out there that will generate that line you are asking for.

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out with help from my web dev friend. He suggested I use Google Maps, and even though I have that whole "layering" issue (with all my events being captured in the canvas and not trickling down to the 'map-canvas' div), I should go and set up events that capture things like zoom and drag, and pipe them along to my Google Map, and the result is prefect for what I am looking for.

So now I have my Easel.js canvas on top of my Google map, and I just have to set up lat/lng positions for my objects when I want them to be part of the map!

Thanks for the help, everyone!